# If in condition on a list object in PYTHON

Tags: python

Hello Sorry I am new to Python, was wondering if there is a way to check if `id` is not in a list I used the following:

```
if item.employee_id not in available_employees.id:
```

**available_employees:**

```
[{'full_name': 'john wick', 'id': 33}, {'full_name': 'mike chung', 'id': 25}, ...]
```

but the above code gives an error:

```
if item.employee_id not in available_employees.id:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of ways to do that

One way is to use the `any()` function, like this:

```
if not any(item.employee_id == e['id'] for e in available_employees):
```

If you're going to do it often, and `available_employees` doesn't change much, it may be convenient to pre-calculate a set:

```
available_employee_ids = {e['id'] for e in available_employees}
if item.employee_id not in available_employee_ids:
```